# How to get two different values of same column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two table `{match_id}_match_main` table and `users` table. `match_main` table stores all players playing for a match.

I want to select name player playing for two teams in same table in two different colums.

Another table `match_master` stores all matches being played:

Desc of `match_master`: match_id,team1_id,team2_id

Desc of `{match_id}_match_main` is : player_id,team_id,goal,yellow,red.

Desc of `users` is : player_id,player_name.

I tried it using join

```
select B.Name as home_player_name,B1.Name as away_player_name 
from {match_id}_match_main A 
inner join users B on A.player_id=B.player_id,
users B1
inner join {match_id}_match_main A1 on A1.player_id=B1.player_id
where A.team_id='t1' and A1.team_id='t2';
```

But this query doesn't provide distinct values, it provides repetitive values.

Comment: What defines a single match in the `match_main` table?

Comment: a `match_id`, actually the real name of table is `match_id_match_main` i just wrote it to simplify things

Comment: That `match_id` column is vital to the answer... Can you please update your question (use [edit]) to give the complete table structure?

Comment: @Nick I've updated the question

Comment: So you have different tables for each match?

Comment: Yea for each match I have a different table to so that each match details can be retrieved later if user want

Comment: It would make your life easier to just have one table and include a `match_id` in the `match_main` table and just `JOIN` `match_main` to `match_master` on the `match_id` value.

Comment: I presume in each `match_main` table there are only two different `team_id` values?

Comment: yes, only two `team_id` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It finds the distinct `team_id` values from `match_main`, then `JOIN`s to `match_main` again twice to get the list of players from each team, along with a row number, which is used to ensure that we don't duplicate pairs of players:

```
SELECT u1.player_name, u2.player_name
FROM (SELECT MIN(team_id) AS team_1, MAX(team_id) AS team_2 FROM match_main) teams
JOIN (SELECT *, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rownumber
      FROM match_main
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) r
      ORDER BY team_id ASC) m1 ON m1.team_id = teams.team_1
JOIN (SELECT *, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS rownumber
      FROM match_main
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) r
      ORDER BY team_id DESC) m2 ON m2.team_id = teams.team_2 AND m2.rownumber = m1.rownumber
JOIN users u1 ON u1.player_id = m1.player_id
JOIN users u2 ON u2.player_id = m2.player_id
```

I've created a small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6a6ca99e4d2e446ad08e788279b08271) so you can see it at work and play with it.

The first derived table:

```
SELECT MIN(team_id) AS team_1, MAX(team_id) AS team_2 FROM match_main
```

finds the two separate teams in each match. The second and third derived tables:

```
SELECT *, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rownumber
FROM match_main
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) r
ORDER BY team_id ASC
```

are essentially the same. They generate row numbers for each row in the `match_main` table, ordering either by `team_id` ascending or descending to get each team's players in the top half of the table. The `m2.rownumber = m1.rownumber` ensures that we get the players from each team in the final result. The final two `JOIN`s to `users` enable us to get the player names from that table.

**Update**

To use the team id's from `match_master` (to ensure that home and away players are sorted properly) you will need to use the `{match_id}` value in the query (there are 3 places); something like this should work:

```
SELECT u1.player_name, u2.player_name
FROM match_master teams
JOIN (SELECT *, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rownumber
      FROM {match_id}_match_main
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn1 := 0) r
      ORDER BY team_id ASC) m1 ON m1.team_id = teams.team1_id
JOIN (SELECT *, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS rownumber
      FROM {match_id}_match_main
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2 := 0) r
      ORDER BY team_id DESC) m2 ON m2.team_id = teams.team2_id AND m2.rownumber = m1.rownumber
JOIN users u1 ON u1.player_id = m1.player_id
JOIN users u2 ON u2.player_id = m2.player_id
WHERE teams.match_id = {match_id}
```

Comment: Can u just explain it to me. :|

Comment: Bro this query sometimes swap the result. Home players are show in away column and Away are shown in home.

Comment: @Poison8 there's no indication in your data as to which is the home and which is the away team. So the results will always be random

Comment: the first column team will always be home and the second column will always be away, is there any way in which we can modify the query according to this.

Comment: @Poison8 Is that in `match_master`?

Comment: yea in `match_master` table

Comment: @Poison8 Take a look at my edit. I think that should solve the swapping